# Higher boundary regularity theorem in Evans for elliptic equation

Tags: sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations, trace-map

I have difficulty with the proof of this theorem:

> Let $m$ be a nonnegative integer, and assume $a^{ij},b^i,c\in C^{m+1}(\overline{U})$, for $(i,j=1,...,n)$ and $f\in H^m(U)$. Suppose that $u\in H^1_0(U)$ is a weak solution of the boundary problem $$\left\{ 
>  \begin{array}{c}
>  Lu=f\hspace{0.2 cm} in \hspace{0.1 cm} U\\ 
>  u=0\hspace{0.3 cm} su \hspace{0.1 cm} \partial U,
>  \end{array}\right.  \hspace{0.8 cm} (1)$$ Assume  $\partial U$ is $C^{m+2}$.  Then $u\in H^{m+2}(U)$, and we have the estimate $$\| u\|_{H^{m+2}(U)}\le C (\| f\|_{H^m(U)}+\| u\|_{L^2(U)}),$$ with $C$ constant.

Consider $U:= B(0,s)\cap \{x_n>0\}\subset \Bbb R^n$, for $s>0$.  We prove by induction. The case $m=0$ is proved from a preceding theorem. Let $\alpha$ be any multi index with $|\alpha|=m+1$ and $\alpha_n=0$. Suppose by induction that $u\in H^{m+2}(U)$.

**My question:** Why $D^{\alpha} u$ vanishes along the plane $\{x_n=0\}$ in the trace sense?

My attempt: Exist $(u_m)_{m\in \Bbb N}\subset C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$ such that $$u_m \rightarrow u\hspace{0.5 cm} in \hspace{0.2 cm} H^{m+2}(U)$$ This implies that $$D^{\alpha} u_m \rightarrow D^{\alpha} u \hspace{0.5 cm} in \hspace{0.2 cm} H^1(U).$$ Then if $T$ is the trace operator  on $U$ $$ T: H^1(U)\rightarrow L^2(\partial U)$$ i have $T(D^{\alpha} u)=\lim _m T(D^{\alpha} u_m)$. How can I continue? Hints?

Comment: $D^\alpha u$ does not need to vanish on the boundary. Consider $m = 1$, $L = -\Delta$, $f \equiv 1$, $U = (0, \pi)$ and $u(x) = \sin(x)$, for instance.

Comment: @Keba you are going to need a 2d or higher d example because of the assumption $\alpha_n=0$

Comment: Ah, missed that, thanks!

Comment: For reference: the OP is talking about Theorem 5 of Section 6.3 of Evans' PDE textbook (at least, according to the 2010 2nd edition). Also @Keba I have given a proof of the claim as an answer below

Comment: @Keba turns out I also misunderstood the OP, I will delete my answer for now

Comment: @CalvinKhor i posted an answer. is it correct?

Comment: @Keba is it correct my answer?

Comment: @DomenicoVuono sorry, I'm not sure yet

Comment: I think that it all right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this works. Add to the induction statement on $m$ that for all multi indices $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=m$ and $\alpha_n=0$, we have that $D^\alpha u\in H^1$ vanishes in the sense of trace. This when $m=0$ is just saying that it satisfies the Dirichlet boundary conditions.

To prove the statement for $|\alpha|=m+1$,
We write $\alpha=a+\alpha’$ for some $|\alpha’|=m$ and $v=D^{\alpha’}u$. By assumption $D^av\in H^1$. By the added induction hypothesis, we have that for sufficiently small $h\neq 0$,
$$ \mathbb D_hv:=\frac{v(x+ah)-v(x)}h \equiv 0$$
in the sense of trace, since $x,x+ah\in\partial U$.
In particular, for all $\epsilon>0$, $\|\mathbb D_h v\|_{L^2(\partial U)}\le \epsilon$. By the section on finite differences in chapter 5, Theorem 3 (ii), we know that taking a weak limit along a subsequence $h_k\to 0$, we have $\mathbb D_{h_k} v \underset{k\to\infty}\rightharpoonup  D^a v$ in $L^2(\partial U)$, with $\|D^a v\|_{L^2(\partial U)}\le \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary,
$$ D^\alpha u|_{x_n=0}=D^a v|_{x_n=0}=0,$$
proving this subclaim of the induction argument.

Would love for readers to comment if they have checked this argument!

Comment: i think that my answer is more simple or not?

Comment: @DomenicoVuono well, I do not understand your answer. Why does it follow ‘easily’ that the limit of $D^\alpha u_m$ is zero? I think it is not guaranteed before sending $m\to \infty$. It’s true that $$ 0=\lim_h \lim_m \frac1h(u_m(x+he_i)-u_m(x)$$ **but** what I want is to take $\lim_h$ first. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Can i change the two limits( h and m)?

Comment: @DomenicoVuono I don’t know and that is why I have written this answer

Comment: @DomenicoVuono hi again, just wondering: have you checked my answer and do you agree that it is not easy to change the two limits? best wishes

Answer (score 0):

Thank to @CalvinKhor i think that i have an answer. By approximation theorem exist $(u_m)_{m\in \Bbb N}\subset C^{\infty}(\overline{U})$ such that $$u_m \rightarrow u\hspace{0.5 cm} in \hspace{0.2 cm} H^{m+2}(U)$$ This implies that $$D^{\alpha} u_m \rightarrow D^{\alpha} u \hspace{0.5 cm} in \hspace{0.2 cm} H^1(U).$$ Now because $T(u)=0$, we obtain that $$\lim _m u_m (x)=0,$$ for every $x\in \{x_n=0\}$, but we can easily verify that $\lim _m D^{\alpha} u_m(x)=0$, for every $x\in \{x_n=0\}$. For the definition of the trace operator we done.

Comment: I think it would be better if we discuss your answer in the comments to your answer, instead of my answer. Can you explain why we can "easily verify that $\lim_m D^\alpha u_m = 0$ on $\{x_n=0\}$"?